# Java makefile with command line arguments

Tags: java, makefile

I have a program that I wish to run and this is how one normally runs it using the command line:

```
java AvlTree.java inputs.txt
```

I wish to create a makefile for executing the above command such that it takes the command line argument which is the file_name: inputs.txt

This is the following makefile I have written:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
        AVLTree.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

I do not know how to tell the makefile to use the command line argument inputs.txt. Moreover, if I type make in the command line, will it execute my program also? Or will it create an executable?

I have placed the source code: AvlTree.java, inputs.txt, and the makefile in the same folder. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have only passing knowledge of make, but from what I can piece together from the above, there is no call to `java` only to `javac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command

```
java AvlTree.java inputs.txt
```

is **not** how one normally runs a java program. It is possible to run a java program that way. But it is not "normal". Because *normally* you **compile** your java program. Which is the step you are currently doing.

```
javac AvlTree.java
java -cp . AvlTree inputs.txt
```

The second command would execute a compiled `AvlTree.class`. Also, you would normally not use `make` or a `Makefile` for Java. You would typically use maven, or ant, or sbt, or gradle. Not `make`. Anyway, you could change your `Makefile` like

```
default: run

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run: classes
    java -cp . AvlTree inputs.txt
```

Comment: Ohh, now I get why I was having a hard time finding java make content since you use Gradle and Maven for it. Also, by editing the makefile, do you mean just appending the instructions from your answer to the original makefile?

Comment: @RishabParmar Almost. Replace the `default` target in your current `Makefile` as above. Then add the `run` target (with the `classes` dependency) at the bottom. And it should behave as you would like. But this is likely to be fragile. Make is an older technology.